# How to go about graphing once I've found the $3$ third roots of $z$, complex numbers

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

Question states: let $z = 8i$, and let $z_{0}, z_{1},$ and $z_{2}$ denote the $3$ third roots of $z$. Find the formulas for $z_{0}, z_{1}, z_{2}$, then draw them on the complex plane.

How I solved, not sure if it is correct:

What I did was rewrite in a+bi form:
$z = 0 + 8i$

then used:
$r = \sqrt{a^{2} + b^{2}}$

and so:
$r = 8$

and then used:

$z = rcos(Θ) + r*i*sin(Θ)$

$z = 8cos(Θ) + r*i*sin(Θ)$

Then $Θ$ must be $π/2$
So,
$z = 8cos(π/2+2kπ) + i*8*sin(π/2+2kπ)$

And since we are looking for the third roots:

$z^{3} = 8cos(π/2+2kπ) + i*8*sin(π/2+2kπ)$

Isolate z:
$z = ( 8cos(π/2+2kπ) + i*8*sin(π/2+2kπ) )^{\frac{1}{3}}$

General template:
$z = 2cos(\frac{π/2+2kπ}{3}) + i*2*sin(\frac{π/2+2kπ}{3})$

Test values:

$k = -1; z = 2cos(-π/2)^{\frac{1}{3}} + i*2*sin(-π/2)^{\frac{1}{3}} = 0 - 2i$

$k = 0; z = 2cos(π/2)^{\frac{1}{3}} + i*2*sin(π/2)^{\frac{1}{3}} = 0 + 2i$

$k = 1; z = 2cos(5π/6)^{\frac{1}{3}} + i*2*sin(5π/6)^{\frac{1}{3}} = -\sqrt{3} + i$

Is this incorrect?

Graphically could I think of these like polar coordinates?
$(-π/2,0), (π/2, 0), (5π/6, -\sqrt{3})$

Thank you

Comment: Why are you raising the cosine and sine terms to the power of 1/3 in the test values? The general template looks right but the angles in the test values are not all divided by 3 as described in the template

Comment: @HR-Physics I don't understand it :( what does it mean?

Comment: I edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

For every complex number you can use  Cartesian ($z = a+ib$) and polar ($z = \sqrt{a^2+b^2} e^{i \theta} , \theta = \tan^{-1}(b/a)$) representations. In polar representation you can also write $z = re^{i\theta} = r(\cos{\theta} + i \sin{\theta})$. Now you have $z=i = 0+1i\to r=1 , \theta = \pi/2$ and therefore $i = e^{i\pi/2}$. In fact this is the principal argument and you may check that 
$$z = 8i = 8e^{i\pi/2} = 8e^{i(\frac{\pi}{2} + 2n\pi)}, \quad n\in \mathbb{Z}.$$
Rewriting the last term in terms of sine and cosine you find what this is correct.

This is a better form that helps you to find roots.

Comment: So then z = r*cos(theta)+r*i*sin(theta) is the same thing as saying z = re^(i*theta)?

Comment: I know how to find 'r' but not sure how I would find theta. I know how to use z = r*cos(theta) +r*i*sin(theta) and I just try to find that theta that would make z the same as the original and work from that.

Comment: So maybe I should use: z = r*cos(theta) + r*i*sin(theta) to first find what theta is, then place that into the exponential form. And since it's three roots, wouldn't I have to cube that? making it 8e^(i*(π/2+2kπ) / 3 )?

Comment: And so 8e^(i*(π/2+2kπ) / 3 ) would be my general template and then I would just start plugging into k values, k = -1, k = 0, k = -1 and see what I get out?

Comment: The angle is obtained by $\theta = \tan^{-1}(b/a) = \tan^{-1}(\infty) = \pi/2$. This is the answer of your first question.

Comment: For finding roots you can write $z^{1/3} = (8)^{1/3} e^{i(\pi/6 + 2n\pi/3)}$. Then for $n=0,\pm 1$ you get the polar representation of roots.

Comment: $k=-1; z_0 = 2e^{ i( \frac{π}{6} + \frac{ 2(-1)π } {3 } ) }$

Comment: $k=0; z_1 = 2e^{ i( \frac{π}{6} + \frac{ 2(0)π } {3 } ) }$

Comment: $k=1; z_2 = 2e^{ i( \frac{π}{6} + \frac{ 2(1)π } {3 } ) }$

Comment: Like this, is this right?

Comment: That's right, except $8$ that should be $8^{1/3}=2$.

Comment: So then the thetas that are generated are as follows: -2π/3,π/6, 5π/6?

Comment: Try again! angles are $-\pi/2 , \pi/6 , 5\pi/6$

Comment: Is this the correct graph? http://imgur.com/a/kwkdo